Unable to unpickle file into a dataframe
import pandas as pd 
import pickle as pic
 
 
file_obj =  open('D:/BAML/Production/EQFICC-Python/FCCV/2005-10-09_RFCV.pickle', 'rb') 

 
data = pic.load(file_obj)


Error : 
runfile('D:/BAML/Production/EQFICC-Python/FCCV/json.py', wdir='D:/BAML/Production/EQFICC-Python/FCCV')
Traceback (most recent call last):
 
  File "D:\BAML\Production\EQFICC-Python\FCCV\json.py", line 15, in <module>
    data = pic.load(file_obj)
 
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Index' on <module '__main__' from 'D:\\BAML\\Production\\EQFICC-Python\\FCCV\\json.py'>

I tried multiple things but not to avail. I want to read the data from the pickle file into a dataframe. I am trying to load a pickle file and try to read into the data to investigate things further. It is just an old code block.

You must provide a [mre] that allows others to reproduce the error.

Since json is the name of a standard library module, you're probably shadowing the name with the name of your file. Try renaming it so that it is not called json.py and see if it helps.

You might want to try using pandas.read_pickle
